# jquery: Making the replacement only on text nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to parse a text as html, making some **changes**, and then again turning in back to plain text.

The **changes** that I'm going to make is bassically replacing some term with another (e.g. `'old'` with `'new'`).

I only want to change the text types, not the attributes and properties of html elements (e.g. the `href` values should not be changed.).

Please see the code:

```
h= '<span myAtrib="something"><a href="old(this SHOULD NOT be changed)">old(this SHOULD be changed)</a></span>';

h=$("<div>"+ h +"</div>").find('span[myAtrib="something"]').html(function (i, oldHtml) {
    oldHtml = oldHtml.replace(/old/g, 'new');
return oldHtml;
}).end().html();
```

How should I make the replacement happen only on text nodes, or at least, how should I filter-out the anchor elements?

Comment: [TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @adeneo , yeah, I have read that answer and got to love it very much. But I didn't figured out how is that related to my question. I don't think I'm parsing html with regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to do the same is

```
h = $("<div id='root'>" + h + "</div>").find('span[myAtrib="something"]').find('*').addBack().contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) != '') {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/old/g, 'new')
    }
}).end().end().end().end().html();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nawSW/)

Comment: I don't want to totally escape elements. Please see my question again: `<a href="old(this SHOULD NOT be changed)">old(this SHOULD be changed)</a>`.

Comment: @Iryn the o/p generated by this is `<a href="old(this SHOULD NOT be changed)">new(this SHOULD be changed)</a> `, I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, but when I use it with my filter (`span[myAtrib="something"]`), then it does not work.

Comment: @Iryn can you edit & share the fiddle to show what you are trying

Comment: Thanks, Arun, but there seems to be cases where the code cannot handle properly. Please see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nawSW/5/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nawSW/4/). I would be glad to know your comments on them. Thanks again.

Comment: @Iryn see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nawSW/6/ and http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nawSW/7/

Comment: I believe that four `.end()` should be used in that case (see http://jsfiddle.net/nawSW/8/). Now, will that cover all the other cases, as well? Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Iryn yes... it will in the previous cases the direct children of `span` was omitted

Comment: So far, I have not found any cases where this code fails, and a jspref test showed me that its faster than the other answer (please let me know if I am wrong). So I choose this as the answer. For others reading this quesion, here is latest version: [http://jsfiddle.net/nawSW/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/nawSW/9/)

Comment: @Iryn also [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nawSW/10/) might be little more cleaner

Answer (score 2):

> How should I make the replacement happen only on text nodes

By recursively iterating over all child nodes/descendants  and testing whether the node is a text node or not:

```
function replace($element, from, to) {
    $element.contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType === 3) { // text node
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(from, to);
        }
        else if (this.nodeType === 1) { // element node
            replace($(this), from, to);
        }
    });
}
var $ele = $("<div>"+ h +"</div>").find('span[myAtrib="something"]')
replace($ele, /old/g, "new");
var html = $ele.end().html();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K6rTP/1/)

You can easily do this without jQuery as well.

Comment: do you see any major performance issues with http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nawSW/1/ - removed the filter + loop http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nawSW/2/

Comment: Looks OK. I just don't like `.find('*')` in general, especially if you don't know how the HTML is structured.